# Apache cron job not running

Tags: php, cron

I have the following in my crontab:

```
*/60 * * * * var/www/html/recalls/php/savesjson.php
```

My intention is for this to run every hour, every day.

However, it's not running. If I go to the location of this file directly and "run" it, it works fine, so I know the PHP is functioning correctly. So, the issue is that it's not running on its own.

I'm wondering if there's more I need to do in terms of permissions or other settings that I'm not aware of. Cron jobs are totally new for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the user running the cron have `+x` permissions on that file?

Comment: You should use `/absolute/path/to/php  /var/www/html/recalls/php/savesjson.php` and of course make sure `savesjson.php` is granted `x` permission for the system user that runs it.

Comment: @smarber What's this part of your comment? `/absolute/path/to/php` I know I need the absolute path to the file, but what's this part?

Comment: It's the output of this command `which php`, this command will display the absolute path of php.

Comment: How deep into the PHP directory do I need to go? `/etc/php` or `/etc/php/7.0/apache2` or deeper than that?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ What should the permission be: 644 or 744 (or something else)?

Comment: `644` is definitely not good, `744` is only good for the owner. First digit is for ower, second digit for group and third digit is for others

Answer (score 1):

The "minutes" column goes from 0 to 59.
You should instead use the "hours" column.

https://www.zimbra.com/docs/ne/6.0.6/administration_guide/C_CronTab%20Jobs.21.2.html

Answer (score 0):

Because in other answer you do not have the cron record here it is:

```
0 * * * * /var/www/html/recalls/php/savesjson.php
```

And it is wise to use absolute path, not relative one